# I am trying to run my first app in grails 2.2.2 .. But it gives me an error.. when i clicked debug

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

> Error 2013-05-16 10:27:41,523 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application:
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder.maximumWeightedCapacity(J)Lcom/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder;
>   Message:
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder.maximumWeightedCapacity(J)Lcom/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder;

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are using maven with grails. The issue arises because of some old version of concurrentlinkedhashmap is pulled somewhere. Use updated version of it, you may use like below:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap</groupId>
<artifactId>concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Note: You should provide a bit more details information about the issue like environment, grails version etc.

Comment: i am using latest version of grails 2.2.2